# Regex performance between `(a|e|i|o|u)? ` and `([aeiou])?`

Tags: regex, performance

It seams that Both `(a|e|i|o|u)?`  and `[aeiou]?` have the same effect, i wonder whether there is any significant difference on performance.

Comment: No, they do not have the same effect. The first one creates a capture group. However `(?:a|e|i|o|u)` and `[aeiou]` have the same effect.

Comment: OK, but you may miss my point if I do care about the capture group

Comment: May be it could be better to change the question to: "... `(a|e|i|o|u)?` and `([aeiou])?` ..."?

Comment: I think it depends on the regex engine and its optimisations, so the question cannot be answered in general. Yet in a well-implemented engine you should not notice a performance difference, as both expressions translate to the same matching behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the example you give there is a significant benefit to using the class over the alternation.

For example:

```
string 'abcde'
regex1 /(a|e|i|o|u)cde/
regex2 /[aeiou]cde/
```

appling either regex1 or regex2 to that string will fail however what goes on under the hood?

Regex1 takes the first character of string and see's if it matches the regex so it checks 'a' against (a|e|i|o|u) which matches, however the regex engine also notes that there are 4 other alternations that could be tested if this one fails later on. It then takes the second character of string and matches it against the second atomic group of the regex 'c' This causes the regex to fail, however it still has 4 other 'states' it can use to try and make a match so the regex engine will go back a step and try to match the first character of the string against e i o u before deciding that the regex will fail completely and exit.

Regex 2 on the other hand decides that the first character of the string 'a' is one of the characters in the class [aeiou] no further states are created and therefore when the second character fails to match it exits with a failure, much quicker than regex1.

There is a lot more to how regex internals work as there are two types of engine (deterministic and non deterministic) but if you're interested in reading more [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) has a very good detailed description of what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for you answer . Let's do a test

Answer (score 0):

The above will both match the same thing, however the difference is that [AEIOU] will start a character class. Rather than writing out (1|2|3|4|5) you could simply write out [1-5], and it will be interpreted as the same thing. Using the other method you would need to re-declare everything you would want to match every time.

More can be read here http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: I wonder whether there is an signicant performance between them ?

Comment: there is, see my post it can get quite significant depending on the regex you're using.

Comment: There could be a significant one, but you should only ever have the use for one. of the above strings in normal situations. Although some regex backends may handle one significantly better than another.